# How to get executable path?

Tags: haxe, openfl

How I can get current executable path in Haxe when programm was launched by lime/openfl?

for example:

```
#if neko
    trace('neko >> ${neko.vm.Module.local().name}');
#elseif cpp
    trace('cpp  >> ${Sys.executablePath()}');
#end
```

will return:

- result for neko target (`lime test linux -64 -neko`):

  neko >>
- result for cpp target (`lime test linux -64 -cpp`):

  cpp >> /usr/local/bin/lime

(this example works fine when I launch compiled files "bin/Main" or "neko bin/Main.n" directly, but I need to get this path when programm was launched by lime/openfl too)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There´s no need to handle it differently when targeting Neko since the Sys class is available for all platforms: http://api.haxe.org/Sys.html

> class **Sys**
>
> no package
>
> *Available on python, neko, java, macro, cpp, lua, php, cs*

Using Sys.executablePath() will return the path to the executable when targeting both Neko and cpp :).

Comment: No, this method is don't work for me (See my question completely). Some haxe-developers answered, that executablePath is buggy and I must use programPath, but this method will available only in haxe 3.3.0+